# GitHub action marks successful run even when dotnet test reports errors

Tags: c#, .net, github-actions

I have a simple problem with `dotnet test` on a windows-runner.
When running multiple tests only the last exit-code is taken into account.

```yaml
- name: Run unit tests
run: |
  dotnet test ./tests/ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj -c release --blame-hang-timeout 15s --blame-hang-dump-type full --blame-crash-dump-type full
  dotnet test ./tests/ProjectB/ProjectB.csproj -c release --blame-hang-timeout 15s --blame-hang-dump-type full --blame-crash-dump-type full
  dotnet test ./tests/ProjectC/ProjectC.csproj -c release --blame-hang-timeout 15s --blame-hang-dump-type full --blame-crash-dump-type full
```

Let's assume `ProjectA` or `ProjectB` do have a test, which fails. Therefore the exit code is non-zero. On `ubuntu-latest` everything is fine and the run is reported as failure, but on `windows-latest` the run is reported as successful.

What worked is to chain the commands via `&&` so that the next command is only run if the current one was successful. The issue with that approach is that the first failing test-suite stops the whole run. I have no problem to introduce a switch between `windows` and non-windows-runner.

Comment: Try running `dotnet test` on the solution instead: `dotnet test ./MyWholeSolution.sln -c release ...`. Dotnet knows which projects of the solution are tests.

Comment: Yeah that helped. Still an odd behavior to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the last exit code is taken into account, is that the 3 calls to dotnet test will be run sequentially.
The output of the "run" will only contain one exit code, so what happens is the 2nd command overrides the first commands result and the 3rd overrides the second.

You have 3 options as I see it:

1. Run a group option such as running the tests at a solution level.
2. Run the tests as a single command using the && as you have suggested.
3. Split the 3 commands into separate steps in the action. e.g.

..

```
- name: Run unit tests projectA
run: |
  dotnet test ./tests/ProjectA/ProjectA.csproj -c release --blame-hang-timeout 15s --blame-hang-dump-type full --blame-crash-dump-type full

- name: Run unit tests projectB
run: |
  dotnet test ./tests/ProjectB/ProjectB.csproj -c release --blame-hang-timeout 15s --blame-hang-dump-type full --blame-crash-dump-type full

- name: Run unit tests projectC
run: |
  dotnet test ./tests/ProjectC/ProjectC.csproj -c release --blame-hang-timeout 15s --blame-hang-dump-type full --blame-crash-dump-type full
```